# Simple svn propset question

Tags: svn

I don't know svn terribly well and not sure how to do the following.  I want to change a single line of the svn:externals property.  On dir, svn:externals has several directories set up

```
>svn propget svn:externals dir
a svn://externalproject/a
b svn://externalproject/b
c svn://externalproject/c
d svn://externalproject/d
```

And I would like to change, say, `b svn://externalproject/b` to `b/b1 svn://externalproject/b1`

that is to say, remove off the externals and replace it with a different one.  How do I do that?  I'm using svn on the command line, version 1.6.9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `propset`, try [`propedit`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re20.html).  It's typically the easier way to modify existing properties.

Answer (score 2):

Use `svn propedit` to edit the properties w/your configured editor.  See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.1